# Using If condition in Ant javac patternset

Tags: ant, compilation, javac, ant-contrib

I would like to exclude some packages to compile, if a property was true or false. Below is my ant script, but I get error:

```
<javac srcdir="src;src-generated" destdir="classes" debug="true" encoding="utf-8">

        <if>
            <equals arg1="${compile.csv}" arg2="false"/> 
            <then>
  <exclude name="${csv.package}"/>
      <exclude name="${excel.package}"/>
            </then>
            </if>
```

javac doesn't support the nested "if" element.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

EDIT:

I defined the property csv.plugin.disabled in the ant build config, properties tab.

```
  <property name="csv.package" value="com/service/transfer/impl/**"/>
  <property name="excel.package" value="com/service/transfer/excel/impl/**"/>


        <javac srcdir="src;src-generated" destdir="classes" debug="true" encoding="utf-8">


      <exclude name="${csv.package}" if="${csv.plugin.disabled}"/>
          <exclude name="${excel.package}" if="${csv.plugin.disabled}"/>
```

I still have these packages included in the classes folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  nested `src` element - you can use there complicated path-like structures (see [Javac Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for full info):

```
<src>
                <fileset dir="src" >
                    <exclude name="${csv.package}" if="${compile.csv}" />
                    <exclude name="${excel.package}" if="${csv.plugin.disabled}"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="src-generated" >
                    <exclude name="${csv.package}" if="${compile.csv}" />
                    <exclude name="${excel.package}" if="${csv.plugin.disabled}"/>
                </fileset>
</src>
```

Comment: Would you please explain how? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `javac` task can take conditional `include/exclude` elements. From the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html):

> This task forms an implicit FileSet and supports most attributes of `<fileset>` (`dir` becomes `srcdir`) as well as the nested `<include>`, `<exclude>` and `<patternset>` elements.

```
<javac srcdir="src;src-generated" destdir="classes" debug="true" encoding="utf-8">
    <exclude name="${csv.package}" unless="${compile.csv}" />
    <exclude name="${excel.package}" unless="${compile.csv}" />
</javac>
```